# What's the difference between normal update and updating using $set operator?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Normal method:

```
module.exports = (_id, newInfo) => {
    return User.update( {_id} , newInfo);
};
```

Using $set operator:

```
module.exports = (_id, newInfo) => {
    return User.update( {_id} , {$set: newInfo} );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

As it stated [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html):

Updating without the use of `$set`,

> if the replacement object is a document, **the matching documents will**
>   **be replaced** (except the _id values if no _id is set)

Whereas we use the `$set`,

> **To update only selected fields**, $set operator needs to be used.
>   Following replacement object replaces author value but leaves
>   everything else intact.

Answer (score 1):

`$Set` creates a new field if there is no existing one

> If the field does not exist, $set will add a new field with the specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type constraint. If you specify a dotted path for a non-existent field, $set will create the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the dotted path to the field.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/